# OBS's 4 Downscale Filters do? difference between 4 OBS encoders?

Tags: discussion

I'm very sorry about No. 1 [What is the difference between OBS encoders?](https://superuser.com/q/1605650/1245428),

> Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.

No. 2. [What do OBS's 4 Downscale Filters do?](https://superuser.com/q/1605653/).

> Update the question so it focuses on one problem only.

How can I make them on topic? I disagree that 1 is a question "seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations". Isn't it self evident that I'm asking about a software's features?

For 2, do you really want me to post three separate questions? I can if you want. I was hoping that if someone can overview the 4 Downscale Filters, and I understand, I won't need to post 3 separate questions.

Comment: If you need to ask about every detail of every option a program has then it is a sign that you need a book rather than a QA site. We are generally here to help you solve specific problems *using* a computer or tool than teach you everything about large topics. If you want ELI5 then there is a Reddit for that, as far as we are concerned that is nothing more than noise.

Answer (score 6):

### In both questions you seem to be utterly in over your head and repeatedly ask “Please explain like I'm 5 (ELI5)…”

#### Questions need to have problems. Your main problem in both questions is you don’t even know the bare basics of that software and explaining that basic level of functionality is out of the scope of this site.

While these questions were edited later on to remove that utterly ridiculous “Please explain like I'm 5 ([ELI5](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/eli5/))…” nonsense, I voted to close both questions earlier when [that “ELI5” was used](https://superuser.com/q/1605650/167207).

In [this one](https://superuser.com/posts/1605650/revisions):

> “Please explain like I'm 5 (ELI5) the 4 encoders below?”

And in [this one too](https://superuser.com/posts/1605653/revisions):

> “Please explain like I'm 5 (ELI5) the four Downscale Filters below?”

In particular [the one where the closure reason was “…product, service, or learning material recommendations…”](https://superuser.com/q/1605650/167207) was and is definitely a request for us to engage in tutoring  you.

If you are asking the community to “…explain like I'm 5…” that shows utterly no level of effort on your part especially for software [that has a very clear, and well written FAQ](https://obsproject.com/wiki/). Saying something like that is just as bad as saying “I am n00b…” and such.

Meaning: Your questions are extremely basic questions that do not require hand-holding for anyone here to explain to you and when you say “…explain like I'm 5…” you are expecting the community to babysit you.

#### This community is here to help you as long as you make some basic effort to get yourself started.

Neither question shows you making any effort at all even with the “Please explain like I'm 5 ([ELI5](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/eli5/))…” stuff removed.

Additionally you say about [the second question](https://superuser.com/q/1605653/):

> “…do you really want me to post three separate questions?”

Nope. All of those questions can be bundled up based on this statement you made in that question:

> “I Googled this, but all the answers were too complicated…”

Here is the problem with that: You state that you believe we want you to post three separate questions when the reality is that question does not have three separate questions, when you have one question:

> “I don’t know what any of this means! Help me and explain it like I am 5 years old!”

Your core issue with *both* questions is you are asking piles of questions without even stating a problem. For example: Why are you obsessing with all these setting specifics? Have you just even used the [Quickstart guide](https://obsproject.com/wiki/OBS-Studio-Quickstart) to get started?

#### “How can I make them on topic?”

In my humble opinion, you can’t. They show no effort and are so open ended that they are simply not questions.

So that said, I would recommend you just use the software with default settings. And if/when you want to ask a question that desires to address an issue *after* that, then that is what the community is for. Something like:

> “I am using OBS but the images are too blocky. Here is my hardware and system specs. What can I adjust to improve things?”